# Get Page URI for QR Code PHP

Tags: plugins, tags

I'm using the QR Code Tag plugin and can't get this to work.

```
<img src="<?php 
global $qrcodetag; 
echo $qrcodetag->getQrCodeUrl('$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']',100,'UTF-8','L',4,0); 
?>">
```

I want a qr barcode to get the current url of the category or page or post in my theme.

Comment: You try to use this code on wordpress.com? I don’t think that would work.

Comment: Nope, on my own install, and my host gives me access to all php functions.

Comment: Okay, I removed the `wordpress.com` tag.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` and add you domain before it so:

```
<img src="<?php 
global $qrcodetag; 
$Path=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$URI='http://www.example.com'.$Path;
echo $qrcodetag->getQrCodeUrl($URI,100,'UTF-8','L',4,0); 
?>">
```

and change `http://www.example.com` to your domain.